# Configuring forms with multiple responses

Tags: asp.net, webforms, sitefinity

I'm using Sitefinity in building my website.
I have created a form using the built-in widget. Can I configure the same form to have multiple responses?
So I can drag the same form in another page and differentiate the responses as if I'm using two different forms.

The thing is that I used MVC to apply the validation messages and extra things so that I don't want to repeat it.
Is there any simple way to achieve this through the settings?

Comment: What code you have tried before asking...

Comment: I tried nothing actually. I'm not sure if this can be achieved in Sitefinity or not

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have a hidden field in the form and then subscribe to the IFormEntryCreatedEvent and modify every response depending on some identifier (ex: page URL).

Read here about how to subscribe to IFormEntryCreatedEvent:
https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-forms-events#iformentrycreatedevent

The subscribtion to form events should happen after sitefinity has intialized (so another event). Example with `Global.asax`

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bootstrapper.Bootstrapped += this.Bootstrapper_Bootstrapped;
}

private void Bootstrapper_Initialized(object sender, ExecutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CommandName == "Bootstrapped")
   {
        EventHub.Subscribe<IFormEntryCreatedEvent>(this.FormEntryCreatedEventHandler);
    }
}
```

Yet again, if you need to diferentiate form responses, the question is, why don't you create another form - it's much cleaner that way. Sitefinity allows you to **duplicate an exiting form** and just give it a different name.

Comment: How can you differentiate the response by just adding success message. you need to add custom implementation that I have posted above...

Comment: Sorry I didn't completely undeerstand what you are trying to do. I updated my response.

Comment: Also, if you need to diferentiate form responses, the question is, why don't you create another form - it's much cleaner. Sitefinity allows you to duplicate an exiting form and just give it a different name.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. I guess I will just create new form as Ivan suggested. It looks better.

Comment: But I think she just want handle both pages response in one form that's because I have suggested to implement custom implementation of form.

Comment: I'll add the form duplication to my answer, since that is the cleanest solution if you want to split the responses.